# Python Hangman not working

Tags: python

So, I've finished my Hangman project for a coding class and it's stuck in a loop where it just keeps asking if you want to play, after that it defines the word to play but it also TELLS you which word to play you're going to play. I think the chained whiles and ifs have some wrong variables.

So, I beg for your help.

```
__author__ = 'Rodrigo Cano'
#Modulos

import random
import re

#Variables Globales

intentos = 0
incorrectos = 0
palabras = [(1,"disclosure"),(1,"thenational"),(1,"foals"),(1,"skepta"),(1,"shamir"),(1,"kanye"),
              (1,"fidlar"),(1,"lcdsoundsystem"),(1,"lorde"),(1,"fkatwigs"),(1,"miguel"),(1,"rtj"),
              (1,"boniver"),(1,"strokes"),(2,"vaporwave"),(2,"witchouse"),(2,"shoegaze"),(2,"memerap"),
              (2,"paulblartisoursaviour"),(3,"glockenspiel"),(3,"aesthetic"),(3,"schadenfreude"),
              (3,"bonvivant"),(3,"swag"),(3,"jue")]
Ascii_Art =[""]
Dibujo = ' '
palabra_a_jugar = ''
Array_Palabra = []
Nuevas_Letras = ''
letras = []
Vidas = 0
i = len(Array_Palabra)


#Funciones

def Definir_Palabra():
    eleccion = int(input("Bienvenido, que categoria quiere usar:"
                     '\n'"1 - Musica que Escuche Mientras Lo Hacia"
                     '\n'"2 - Generos Musicales"
                     '\n'"3 - Palabras Pretenciosas"))
    palabras_escogidas = [i for i in palabras if eleccion in i ]
    palabra_a_jugar = str(palabras_escogidas[random.randint(0,len(palabras_escogidas))].__getitem__(1))
    Array_Palabra = len(palabra_a_jugar) * ['*']
    return palabra_a_jugar, Array_Palabra

def Letras_En_Palabra(letra):
    letras = [i for i, x in enumerate(palabra_a_jugar) if x == letra]
    for i in range (0, len(letras)):
        Array_Palabra[letras] = letra
    return letras,Array_Palabra

def Letras_Jugadas(letra):
    for i in range(0,len(Nuevas_Letras)):
        Nuevas_Letras = re.findall(letra,Nuevas_Letras[i])
        if Nuevas_Letras != []:
            return 1
    return Nuevas_Letras
def Eleccion():
    Choice = input("Quiere Jugar?")
    if Choice == 'si':
        Choice = 1
    elif Choice == 'no':
        Choice = 0
    return Choice

# Juego
Choice = Eleccion()
def Juego(Choice):
    i = len(Array_Palabra)
    while Choice == 1:
        print(Definir_Palabra())
        while i != 0 :
            tiro = str.lower(input("adivine una letra"))
            if Letras_Jugadas(tiro) != 1:
                Nuevas_Letras = Nuevas_Letras + tiro
                letras = Letras_En_Palabra(tiro)
                if Letras_Jugadas(tiro) != []:
                    i = len(letras) - 1
                    print("Letras Utilizadas",Nuevas_Letras)
                    print(Letras_En_Palabra(tiro))
                else:
                    Vidas = Vidas + 1
                    Dibujo += Ascii_Art[Vidas]
                    print("WROOOONG")
                    print(Dibujo)
                    print("Letras Utilizadas",Nuevas_Letras)
                if Vidas ==9:
                    i = 0
            else:
                print("Letra ya Juagada",Nuevas_Letras)
        Eleccion()

Juego(Choice)
```

Comment: So we're supposed to help debug your code with a vague description of the problem and all of the code in spanish?

Comment: Which line is `if you want to play`?

Comment: Choice = Elección(), is the one that should change the value.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your `Juego` should be `Choice = Eleccion()`, otherwise, you're not actually changing the value of `Choice`, so the loop continues indefinitely.

```
def Juego(Choice):
    i = len(Array_Palabra)
    while Choice == 1:
        print(Definir_Palabra())
        while i != 0 :
            tiro = str.lower(input("adivine una letra"))
            if Letras_Jugadas(tiro) != 1:
                Nuevas_Letras = Nuevas_Letras + tiro
                letras = Letras_En_Palabra(tiro)
                if Letras_Jugadas(tiro) != []:
                    i = len(letras) - 1
                    print("Letras Utilizadas",Nuevas_Letras)
                    print(Letras_En_Palabra(tiro))
                else:
                    Vidas = Vidas + 1
                    Dibujo += Ascii_Art[Vidas]
                    print("WROOOONG")
                    print(Dibujo)
                    print("Letras Utilizadas",Nuevas_Letras)
                if Vidas ==9:
                    i = 0
            else:
                print("Letra ya Juagada",Nuevas_Letras)
        """
        >>>> CHANGED <<<<
        """
        Choice = Eleccion()
```

Otherwise, the way you had it simply calls the function `Eleccion` but *doesn't* return the value to the `Choice` variable in scope of `Juego` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to indent :)

```
import random

# defining the main method
def main():
print "Hello Welcome to Python Hangman!!!"
random_word()
user_input()
# defining the dictionary_list to be used as the guessing word
def random_word():
dictionary_list= ["ant", "bath", "car", "dog", "electric", "foil", "grape", "heat", "ice", "jolly",
                   "knight", "lemon", "money", "need", "open", "park", "quote", "rough", "salty",
                   "teach", "under", "village", "warmth", "xavier", "yelp", "zipper"]


# making rand global so it can be used within deifferent functions
global rand
# randomly choosing a word from the dictionary_list and assign to the variable rand
rand = random.choice(dictionary_list)
return rand

# user guessing
def user_input():
guesses = 0
wrong_guess = 0
guess_left = 10
correct_letters_list = ""
wrong_letters_list =""
print "You have \033[1;34;15m 10 \033[0;30;15m guesses"

#getting the length of the word
length = len(rand)
print "The word is: " + "\033[1;35;15m" + str(length) + "\033[0;30;15m" + " characters long"

# loops around until the user has used all their 6 guesses are used up
while guesses < 10 :
    guess = raw_input("Guess a Letter [a-z]: ").lower()
    # stop case sensitivity
    # if the letter guessed by the user is in rand string print correct else print wrong
    if guess in rand:
        correct_letters_list += guess
        print "\033[1;32;15mcorrect"
        print "correct letters:"
        print "\033[0;30;15m" + correct_letters_list
        print "incorrect letters:"
        print "\033[0;30;15m" + wrong_letters_list
        # each time the user guesses + 1 to the guesses tally
        guesses +=1
        guess_cal = guess_left - guesses
        print "You have: " + str(guess_cal) + " guesses left"
        # if rand contains guess more than once tell user
        if rand.count(guess) > 1 :
            print "The word contains the letter " + str(guess) + " " +  "\033[1;36;15m" + str(rand.count(guess)) + "\033[0;30;15m" + " times"
    else:
     wrong_letters_list += guess
     print "\033[1;31;15mwrong"
     print "incorrect letters:"
     print "\033[0;30;15m" + wrong_letters_list
     print "correct letters:"
     print "\033[0;30;15m" + correct_letters_list
     guesses += 1
     guess_cal = guess_left - guesses
     print "You have: " + str(guess_cal)  + " guesses left"
     wrong_guess += 1
     if wrong_guess == 1:
         print "________      "
         print "|      |      "
         print "|             "
         print "|             "
         print "|             "
         print "|             "
     if wrong_guess == 2:
         print "________      "
         print "|      |      "
         print "|      0      "
         print "|             "
         print "|             "
         print "|             "
    if wrong_guess == 3:
        print "________      "
        print "|      |      "
        print "|      0      "
        print "|     /       "
        print "|             "
        print "|             "
    if wrong_guess == 4:
        print "________      "
        print "|      |      "
        print "|      0      "
        print "|     /|      "
        print "|             "
        print "|             "
    if wrong_guess == 5:
        print "________      "
        print "|      |      "
        print "|      0      "
        print "|     /|\     "
        print "|             "
        print "|             "

    if wrong_guess == 6:
        print "________      "
        print "|      |      "
        print "|      0      "
        print "|     /|\     "
        print "|     /       "
        print "|             "

    if wrong_guess >= 7:
        print "________      "
        print "|      |      "
        print "|      0      "
        print "|     /|\     "
        print "|     / \     "
        print "|             "
    choice = raw_input("Do you wish to guess the word? (Y/N): ").lower()
    if choice == 'y':
        word = raw_input("Please enter the word: ").lower()
        if word == rand:
            print "Well Done you Guessed Correctly, the word was: " + rand
            # if the user has guessed correctly + 10 to the guesses tally to end the game
            guesses += 10
        else:
            print "Incorrect, Game Over!! The word was: " + rand
            guesses += 10
    # if user chooses n continue with the game
    if choice == 'n':
        continue

# if the user has used up all their 10 guesses print Game Over!!
if guesses == 10:
    print "End of Game you ran out of guesses!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```